# How to update minDate and maxDate for start date and end date dynamically using Materialize 1.0.0' s Datepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker, materialize

I'm new to javascript and using Materialize as CSS framework.
I'm implementing two datepickers for a start and end date. I'm struggling with setting the `maxDate` and `minDate` dynamically.
`maxDate` for the start datepicker shouldn't exceed the date of the end datepicker if the latter is selected.
`minDate` for the end datepicker should not be below the date of the start datepicker if the latter is selected.
I wonder how I would do that with Materialize version 1.0.0.

Here is my code (which is not working):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col s12 m3"></div>
   <div class="col s12 m6">
      <h3>StartDate</h3>
      <div class="input-field">
         <input id="input_from" type="date" name="StartDate" class="datepicker">
      </div>
      <h3>EndDate</h3>
      <div class="input-field">
         <input id="input_to" type="date" name="EndDate" class="datepicker">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col s12 m3"></div>
</div>

</div>
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
< script >
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      var start_options = {
         setDefaultDate: true,
         autoClose: false,
         showClearBtn: true,
         format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
         disableWeekends: true,
         showDaysInNextAndPreviousMonths: true,
         firstDay: 1
         };

      var end_options = {
         setDefaultDate: true,
         autoClose: false,
         showClearBtn: true,
         format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
         disableWeekends: true,
         showDaysInNextAndPreviousMonths: true,
         firstDay: 1,
         };


      let StartDate = document.querySelector('#input_from');
      let EndDate = document.querySelector('#input_to');
      let start_instance = M.Datepicker.init(StartDate, start_options);
      let end_instance = M.Datepicker.init(EndDate, end_options);


      if (start_instance.date) {
         end_options.minDate = start_instance.date;
         
      };
      if (end_instance.date) {
         start_options.maxDate = end_instance.date;
      }


   })

</script>
```